# Print the request step response in groovy script step using variable

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a requirement in which I need to print XML response in `Groovy Script` test step

- Name of SOAP Request test step is **Licensed**

When I write

```
log.info context.expand('${Licensed#Response}')
```

I get right response

But I have a requirement where user is not aware of the code

```
def requestname=Licensed //user will   enter request name here

log.info context.expand($'{requestname"#Response}')
```

I don't get valid response

I want to declare a variable and use and print xml response

Comment: log.info context. expand($'{requestname"+#Response"}')

Comment: Also I tried def requestfull=Licensed#Response log.info context.expand($'{requestfull}) that also does not work

Comment: earlier right response code was log.info context.expand('${Licensed#response}')

Comment: Do you mean to say that the request step name is put into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need in order use the step name as parameter / variable. You have a trivial error in your code snippet.

```
//You missed quotes  
def requestname='Licensed'   
//Your were using quotes incorrectly   
log.info context.expand('${'+requestname+'#Response}')
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: @GauriAparadh, Glad to know that the answer is helpful. I would appreciate if you take a moment to [accept it as answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)